# fill array with character in string

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that fill the array with the specific character in a string.

For example

```
String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";
String[] arr = new String[5];
int x = 0;    

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = s.charAt(x);
    x += 2;
}
```

An error shows up "Incompatible types"

How to fix this? I'm new to java.

---

Solved! Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `s.toCharArray()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning a character to a position in a String array. In your code, arr[i] refers to a String, and s.charAt(x) is a char.

It seems like arr should be a char array instead of a String array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're getting at here, so you have two options.

1. A `char` array:

   ```
   String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";
   char[] arr = new char[5];


   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       arr[i] = s.charAt(x);
       x ++;
   }
   ```
2. A string array where the strings are single characters:

   ```
   String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";
   String[] arr = new String[5];


   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       arr[i] = s.substring(x, x+1);
       x ++;
   }
   ```